# Get resultset when running a select query

Tags: sql-server

How can I get the resultset when still running a select query.

It can be simulated running a select query on SQL Server Management Studio, the resultset will be displayed when query still running.

The rows ared added by yield, I presume.

Comment: Are you asking about result sets that sometimes come back all at once and some that trickle in and you can see the result set getting bigger?

Comment: If you are using an `ORDER BY...` clause in your select statement, the partial results can't be shown in the SQL Server Management Studio results window until they are completely finished, but if you aren't ordering your results, then the window will populate with the results as they come in.  It sounds like you're implying you want to get the results in another program besides server management studio, but you haven't given us any other information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @dfundako exactly

Comment: @RodrigoReis I believe that has to do with the operators in your execution plan, which you don't really directly control. If it is a lazy operator and can bring back results as they come, then you will see more trickle in. If it is an eager operator and it has to have the entire dataset first, you won't see it. I could be wrong though.